# sqlite queries return null

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this code for sqlite queries;

```
public Cursor getTestData() 
     { 
         try 
         { 
             String sql ="select * from tbl_game where status='0' order BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"; 

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null); 
             if (mCur!=null) 
             { 
                mCur.moveToNext(); 
             } 
             return mCur; 
         } 
         catch (SQLException mSQLException)  
         { 
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString()); 
             throw mSQLException; 
         } 
     }
```

But I don't know why does is return a null value.

When I remove the where clause it returns a value.

This is my table;

```
id  |   name    |   image   |   description |   status

1   |menard mabunga |   menard  |   Sample only |   0
2   |francis reyes  |   francis |   Test only   |   1
```

Comment: What returns a null value? rawQuery?

Comment: Please show the code that calls `getTestData` and checks for null.

Comment: I'm using this code to call getTestData,

`final TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);         
     mDbHelper.createDatabase();       
     mDbHelper.open(); 
     
     Cursor testdata = mDbHelper.getTestData(); 
      
     
     
     final String name = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "name");
     final String imge = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "image");
     final String desc = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "description");`

Comment: @iamnards bit late but might as well create an answer for this. That way you can have formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The values in the `status` column look as if they might be numbers, not strings. Try using `where status=0` (without quotes) instead.

Comment: I remove the quotes & try moveToFirst, but nothing happens